# Control Event (Changed) In DataTable

Tags: vb.net

Helo:

How to overcome the problem of [RowChanged] event within the [DataTable] in the [DataGridView].

Explanation: You have created a column in the dataTable to find out which rows have been modified, in order to facilitate the knowledge of these rows to update them in the database, but the problem in the event(Row_Changed), can not be explained by more words in the code, see the column of (ISCHANGE) after modifying any row and cover the The Save button you find takes the value True and then False;

```
Public Class Class1

Public Table As DataTable

Sub New()
    Table = New DataTable
    Table.Columns.Add("IsChange", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))
    Table.Columns.Add("TeacherName", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    Table.Columns("IsChange").DefaultValue = False
    Dim dr As DataRow = Table.Rows.Add
    dr("TeacherName") = "X1"
    dr = Table.Rows.Add
    dr("TeacherName") = "X2"
    dr = Table.Rows.Add
    dr("TeacherName") = "X3"
    dr = Table.Rows.Add

    AddHandler Table.RowChanged, New DataRowChangeEventHandler(AddressOf Row_Changed)
End Sub

Sub New(SourceDataTable As DataTable)
    'Import DataTable 
    Table = SourceDataTable
End Sub

Public Sub Save()
    GotoChange = False 'disable the event (Row_Changed)
    For ALoop As Integer = 0 To Table.Rows.Count - 1
        '=======================================
        'Here Code Save To DataBase
        '
        '
        '=======================================
        Table(ALoop)("IsChange") = False 'RowChanged =False
    Next
    GotoChange = True 'Enabled the event (Row_Changed)
End Sub

Dim GotoChange As Boolean = True 'This variable is to disable the event (Row_Changed)
Private Sub Row_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataRowChangeEventArgs)
    If Not GotoChange Then Exit Sub
    If e.Action = DataRowAction.Add Or e.Action = DataRowAction.Change Then
        If CBool(e.Row("IsChange")) = False Then
            MsgBox("IsChange")
            e.Row("IsChange") = True 'If [True] this means that the row has been changed 
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Form Code :
Change Any Row Then Button Save:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim A As New Class1
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = A.Table
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim A As New Class1(Me.DataGridView1.DataSource)
    'Change Value Any Row Then Button Save
    'Here Problem: Show Column(IsChang) After Save 
    'The value First (False) Then (True)
    A.save()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you remove the c# tag... This is VB!   Look at the DataRows DataRowState properties and the DataTables GetChanges method...You don't need a column to keep track of whats changed.

Comment: Also you don't need a global variable to block your event handler code. As you have an AddHandler you have also a RemoveHandler.

Comment: Have you considered using DataTable.GetChanges instead of checking for changes via an event for row changed as also suggested by Wheels73. I can provided an example if interested that works from a language extension method which returns (if there are changes) in six tables where the function returns an instance of a class that represents all six changes including primary keys for deleted rows (I see you are not concerned with them but might be helpful down the road)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly required